# Diseño de la estructura de datos para productos

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, diseño-de-clases

Necesito diseñar la estructura de las tablas con los datos de productos para cumplir los siguientes requisitos:

1. Un producto consta de los siguientes campos: EAN, CN, descripción, pvp
2. Existen varios tipos de usuario que acceden a los productos. Los tipos de usuario no son estables, pueden añadirse o suprimirse en cualquier momento.
3. Cualquiera de los campos de los productos puede variar en función del tipo de usuario que lo visualiza. Por ejemplo:

Tenemos tres usuarios:

- 1 - Pepe - invitado
- 2 - Manolo - cliente
- 3 - Vicente - vip

Tenemos este producto con estos datos por defecto:

- 8470001234567 - 123456 - Iphone X - 799€

Los usuarios invitado en lugar de ver estos datos ven los siguiente:

- 8431239876547 - 987654 - Iphone X - 849€

Los usuarios cliente ven los datos por defecto y los usuarios vip ven:

- 8470001234567 - 654321 - Iphone X Rebajado - 709€

Esto quiere decir que, un usuario ve los datos por defecto de un producto dado a no ser que exista una excepción para su tipo. La excepción puede afectar a cualquier campo (excepto al id).

Se me ocurre esta estructura:

1. **PRODUCTOS**: **id**, ean, cn, descripcion, pvp
2. **PRODUCTO_EXCEPCION**: **id_producto**, **id_tipo_usuario**, ean, cn, descripcion, pvp

He comprobado que con esta estructura se realizan bastantes consultas, ¿Se os ocurre alguna forma de optimizar esto para que no sea necesario realizar tantas consultas?

Nota 1: los productos están contenidos dentro de ofertas que tienen cierto número de productos
Nota 2: uso Laravel. El modelo oferta tiene una relación con productos, es decir, obtengo los productos de la siguiente forma: $oferta->productos()

Comment: En el ejemplo del Iphone X el id y el ean de las tres versiones son números distintos. Por lo tanto, no es que cada tipo de usuario vea datos diferentes para cada producto, es que **cada tipo de usuario verá productos diferentes**. Al menos desde el punto de vista de la base de datos esos tres son productos distintos, independientemente de cómo se llamen. ¿Realmente es eso lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Porque luego dices "un usuario ve los datos por defecto de un producto dado a no ser que exista una excepción para su tipo". En tal caso el diseño que estás implementando no es eficiente. Sería preferible tener una tabla "Productos" con la información que sea independiente del usuario, otra tabla "Usuarios" y una tercera tabla "X" que sea la relación entre Productos y Usuarios donde SÍ pones la información a mostrar a cada usuario (descripción, precio, etc.).

Comment: Sobre el EAN que es distinto para distintos usuarios es lo que quiero hacer. Serán muy pocos casos, pero con que haya alguno es suficiente. Existen determinados artículos como puede ser un expositor que lleva varios articulos que se venden conjuntamente al que el vendedor le inventa el codigo y quiere que sea distinto para cada tipo de usuario.

Comment: Sobre la tabla pivot ya lo he contemplado, pero no lo veo, porque los campos susceptibles de variar son todos, el unico coincidente sería el id. Esto significa que tendria que tener todos los campos del producto en la tabla pivot y un registro por cada tipo de usuario. El 95% de los articulos van a ser identicos para todos los usuarios, por lo que si tengo 10 tipos de usuarios tendría el 95% de los productos repetidos 10 veces con los mismos datos y eso me parece poco eficaz

Comment: Entiendo. Pero no creo que sea necesario que en la tabla pivot tengas todos los productos repetidos por cada tipo de usuario (sería muy problemático actualizar y modificar los datos). Puedes tener cada producto solo una vez para el usuario "normal" (genérico) además de las pocas excepciones que existan para otros usuarios.

En las consultas SELECT bastaría con añadirle un CASE con dos posibilidades. Si existe el par producto-usuario (la excepción) entonces muestras esa información. En caso contrario muestras la información del genérico. (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).

Comment: Tal vez exista una mejor solución, pero esta es la que se me ocurre. Espero que sea de ayuda. Ya nos cuentas ;-)